# Setup Firebase to validate Google Billing purchase tokens

Tags: database, firebase, function, in-app-purchase, token

I don't know the common way but I have the following idea:

The client that uses my app sends a purchase token that it recieved after a successful purchase from the google play billing api to my firebase (as far as I understood, there are firebase functions) which checks if the token is valid and then updates the database. Unfortunately I just started experimenting with firebase, so far I only have authentication working. How can I implement my idea? Is it even possible or are there better ways to do that?